# Android SDK fails to work (eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

Hi I'm starting to experiment with the android SDK, I've connected my phone to my computer (Windows 7, Intel Centrino) And Installed the Android SDK, the devices is recognized and I CAN choose for example DDMS to see my phone (HTC Legend) data is loaded interaction with the phone gives result on the screen so that looks good...

Also the SDK is installed for eclipse. And it's recognized build target seem to work and I can start a project...

Now the less good stuff

I can't see the application. If i use run there is no respond to the phone, no messages just nothing is happening. Also I noticed that any virtual device can never start. And a other strange thing is that most things related to DDMS in eclipse DO NOT WORK. they give errors that look like:

[image]

My question is how do I solve this?

Comment: Try opening the Android SDK manager and deleting and re-downloading  everything in the Tools group. Then try deleting and reinstalling the Android Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Did u allowed non market apps to run on u r device ?

Settings > Application settings > check the ticker for 'unknown sources'.